# Can I evaluate the quality of my OS random numbers?

Tags: random

Is there a software or website that implements tests of randomness to check if my random numbers are of cryptography quality ?

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/394/94291

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check randomness of random number generators?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83254/how-to-check-randomness-of-random-number-generators), [Testing a hardware random number generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47475/testing-a-hardware-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [randomness tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test) that in software includes the [Diehard test suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests). This is available in Linux distributions as the [dieharder](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder) command.